# Автоматическая замена url на правильный

Tags: php, codeigniter, framework

У меня например сейчас URL имеет такой вид 1-perwaja_nowost.html и отображается новость с id 1, а если URL сделать 2-perwaja_nowost.html то отображается новость с id 2, как сделать что бы при вводе id 2 URL принимал вид 2-vtoraja_novost.html?

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю сделать так:

1. Храните URL новости (весь сегмент, н-р, "2-vtoraja_novost") в БД (в таблице новостей или в какой-то общей таблице SEO)
2. При сохранении новости формируйте для неё этот URL, например, из названия: `$data['url'] = $id . '-' . translit($data['name']);` Вместо названия можете подставлять какую-то другую строку. Готовые функции для транслитерации легко нагуглить, например, https://htmlweb.ru/php/example/translit.php
3. В роутинге пропишите что-то типа `$route['novosti/(:any)'] = 'news/show/$1';`, где `news` - это контроллер новостей, а `show` - метод, который показывает новость.
4. В методе `function show($url){}` получайте из БД новость по `$url`, а не id. Если запись не найдена, показывайте страницу 404.
5. Если вы хотите, чтобы с "2-perwaja_nowost.html" был прям редирект на "2-vtoraja_novost.html", тогда в методе `show` из url вычлените id новости, получите по нему запись новости и сделайте `redirect('url новости с id=2');`.

Comment: У меня так и сделано, но в адресной строке не происходит замены адреса, а мне именно это нужно

Comment: @AlukardNosferatu Покажите свой код, которым вы пытаетесь сделать эту "замену". Это или весь код метода, из которого вы делаете `redirect`, или правила редиректа в `.htaccess`, или роутинг или что-то ещё. Пока непонятно, как именно вы делаете  замену и что именно в ней не работает.

Comment: в роутере 
$routes->get('news/(:num-:any)', 'Home::show_news/$1');
в контроллере
public function show_news($id = null)
 {
  $data = [
   'title' => 'Полная публикация ',
  ];
  $data = $this->rows($id, $data);
  page_view('site', 'show_full', $data);

 }

Comment: а так мне нужно чтобы адресной строке автоматически из 2-perwaja_nowost.html менялось на 2-vtoraja_novost.html

Comment: @AlukardNosferatu Тогда, как я писала в п.5 в ответе выше. Так получилось?

Comment: у меня переходит на вторую новость, просто чпу не обновляется, сейчас 2-perwaja_nowost.html тоже самое что и 2-vtoraja_novost.html, а мне нужно что бы он в адресной строке при вводе например id 2 автоматически формировал 2-vtoraja_novost.html

Comment: @AlukardNosferatu А адресной строке браузера без редиректа url не изменить. Вы воспользовались функцией `redirect()` https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=redirect#redirect ? Добавили эту логику "если у полученной по id записи url отличается от текущего в адресной строке, то сделать редирект на правильный url"? Типа `if ($url !== $data['url']) { redirect($dat['url']); }`, где `$url` - текущий url, а `$data['url']` - это правильный url из БД. Получилось? Если нет, напишите конкретно, как вы сделали и что не получается.